# Filtering through Wordpress Posts using a Month data format in Vue.js

Tags: wordpress, vue.js, filtering, posts

I am wondering what is the best way to filtering through Wordpress Posts using a Month data formate in Vue.Js

I get my data through WP_JSON posts, which is great but i need to create a dropdown that when a user selects a month "September" for example then the page will only show the Posts that were created in September.

Again i am using Vue.js

Any help would be great.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use filter, something like:

```
Vue.filter('filterByMonth', function(posts, selectedMonth) {
  if (selectedMonth === 0) {
    return posts; // Return all
  }
  return posts.filter(post => {
    const postDate = new Date(post.date);
    const postMonth = postDate.getMonth() + 1; // Months are indexed from 0
    return postMonth === selectedMonth;
  });
});
```

and then in template you can use some dropdown

```
<template>
  <div>
    <label for="monthSelect">Select Month:</label>
    <select id="monthSelect" v-model="selectedMonth">
      <option value="0">All</option>
      <option value="1">January</option>
      <option value="2">February</option>
      <!-- Add options for all months -->
    </select>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="post in filteredPosts" :key="post.id">{{ post.title }}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>
```

As a final step you need to define template and variables and connect filter.

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      selectedMonth: 0, // Default to All
      posts: [ /* Your WordPress posts array here */ ]
    };
  },
  computed: {
    filteredPosts() {
      return this.$options.filters.filterByMonth(this.posts, this.selectedMonth);
    }
  }
};
```